# Can't access my IIS site online

Tags: dns, hosting, virtual-machine

I created a IIS site in my windows server 2012 virtual machine. I want to be able to access it online on my android phone. I can access it locally on the server. The ip address of the server is `199.86.19.2` and for the IIS site its `192.168.113.133`. Also the server is a dynamic ip. I have tried using an online site called noip.com to make a domain. I created a domain

`mydomain.no-ip.biz` and gave it the ip address `192.168.113.133`. I even installed the client program so it keeps my ip up to date. However when I visit `mydomain.no-ip.biz`. it says it cannot be found.

Does anyone know what is wrong here?

Thanks.

Comment: Such questions should go to Server Fault, and it has little or no relationship with IIS. You are supposed to fully understand how to set up forwarding in the network, and that's not related to programming at all.

Answer (score 0):

`192.168.113.133` is your local IP address on your network.  `199.86.19.2` is your external IP address that your IPS assigned to your server (until it expires).  I'm assuming you are doing this at home so you would need to make sure if you have a router, you need to configure it to set it up to port forward to your local IP address.

Set your 'mydomain.no-ip.biz' ip address to `199.86.19.2` and make sure your router (if you have one) is forwarding to `192.168.113.133`.

Comment: But how does this work if you want your site to be online no matter where u are getting an internet connection to run the server from? For example, if I am at home I would need to configure the router to do ip forwarding, but what if I run my server on my laptop and its connected to a school internet where I can't edit the router settings. Isn't there a general way to do this?

Comment: You can't.  I'm pretty sure your school does not allow machines on it's network to accessed from the internet.

Your "webserver" should not be moving along with you like that.  Why would you want a website to only be "online" when your laptop is on?